# How to host a Wcf service in Windows server 2008 R2?

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, hosting, windows-server-2008-r2

I am toothily new to server side and I want host a web service in my newly created windows server 2008 r2 virtual machine. however i cannot get it up there. I am getting errors after such as MIME type, sometimes files get downloaded, Permission errors, protocol mapping.

Therefore, I would like to know how to host a WCf Application from the begining. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are excellent guides you can refer to host a WCF service in Windows Server 2008 R2:

http://broomandan.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-configure-windows-server-2008-to.html

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2014/02/16/wcf-service-manual-deployment-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx